# ¿Como permitir activar otro radio button, hasta que se cumpla una condición, jquery?

Tags: jquery

tengo una lista de radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="cupon_check" class="cupon_check" value="' + response.data[i].Tipo_cupon + '"/>'
```

Con esta funcion al seleccionar un radio button desencadena una serie de funciones, pero como puedo hacer la validación que cuando quieran seleccionar otro radio button deben asegurarse que hay productos a eliminar de una lista, por lo tanto no permita seleccionar otro radio button, caso contrario si pueden seleccionar otro radio button.
Básicamente es hasta que el arreglo `productos_seleccionados` ya no tenga ningun objeto.

```
$('#cupones_bienvenida').on('click','.cupon_check', function(e){
    console.log("Cupon seleccionado");
    var cupones  = $(this).closest('.cupones');
    cod_cupon = cupones.find('.cod_cupon').text();
    var tipo_cupon = $(this).val();
    console.log(cod_cupon);
    if (productos_seleccionados.length >0) {
        console.log("Por favor debe eliminar los productos seleccionados");
    } else{
        cuponesDescuentoProducto1(idPedido);
        cuponesDescuentoProducto3(idPedido);
        cuponesDescuentoProducto4(idPedido);
        $('.tbla-productos1').show();
        $('.tbla-productos3').show();
        $('.tbla-productos4').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Crea dos escuchadores que reaccionen cuando añadas y elimines, respectivamente, un producto a la lista.

```
$('.anadir_a_lista').on('click', function(e){
    $('#cupones_bienvenida .cupon_check').attr('disabled', true);
}

$('.quitar_de_lista').on('click', function(e){
    if (productos_seleccionados.length != 0){
        $('#cupones_bienvenida .cupon_check').attr('disabled', true);
        //AQUÍ AVISAS AL USUARIO QUE DEBE VACIAR LA LISTA
    } else {
        $('#cupones_bienvenida .cupon_check').attr('disabled', false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias eso funciona bien, solo que cuando el usuario intente seleccionar otro radio button debo mostrarle el mensaje que debe dejar vacía la lista de productos seleccionados y para este caso como le agregaría esa parte.
Muchas gracias de antemano.